# XSLT - add new node by analyzing text node

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a XML like follows,

```
<doc>
    <chap>
        The bowler delivers the ball 
        to the batsman who attempts to 
        hit the ball with his bat away from 
        the fielders so he can run to the 
        other end of the pitch and score a run.
    </chap>
</doc>
```

My requirement is add new nodes named `<p>` to `<chap>` text node where add  `<p>` node to every new line.

So, desired output is,

```
<doc>
    <chap>
        <p>The bowler delivers the ball</p>
        <p>to the batsman who attempts to</p>
        <p>hit the ball with his bat away from</p> 
        <p>the fielders so he can run to the</p> 
        <p>other end of the pitch and score a run.</p>
    </chap>
</doc>
```

Can you give me a suggestion how can I do this in XSLT using regex and separate the text by line feed (`#xA`).

I tried to do this task but could not think of a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`xsl:analyze-string`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string) to select the text between spaces and newlines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chap/text()">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s*(.*)\n">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <p><xsl:sequence select="regex-group(1)"/></p>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or you could use [`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) to split on newlines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chap/text()">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\n')[normalize-space()]">
            <p><xsl:sequence select="normalize-space()"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```